# I'm trying to verify my ISO for Ubuntu in windows 10 using WSL Bash command line, Im not getting a DSA key no matter what I do

Tags: bash, windows, iso

I just want to know if I have no DSA key just an RSA key if my ISO is ok. I ran everything,  It says the ISO is OK when I check it and verifies with the RSA key but is this OK with no DSA key or is there something else I should do, or something i missed? Sorry for the formatting and any mistakes in advance total noob here. I'm on Windows 10 home running WSL, when I check the version in Powershell it just says:

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu (Default).
```

Here's the code:

```
shunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS.txt (tried with and with out .txt)
gpg: Signature made Thu Apr 23 09:46:21 2020 EDT
gpg: using RSA key D94AA3F0EFE21092

shunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver khp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keshunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver khp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/home/shunix/.gnupg/S.dirmngr' failed: IPC connect call failed
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr

shunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
gpg: can't open signed data 'SHA256SUMS'
gpg: can't hash datafile: No such file or directory

shunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS.txt
gpg: Signature made Thu Apr 23 09:46:21 2020 EDT
gpg: using RSA key D94AA3F0EFE21092 (every example I've seen has an RSA and a DSA key that shows this is my main concern)_
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key

shunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0XD94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: "0XD94AA3F0EFE21092" not a key ID: skipping

shunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: public key "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) cdimage@ubuntu.com" imported
gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg: imported: 1

shunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ gpg --keyid-format long --list-keys --with-fingerprint 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092
pub rsa4096/D94AA3F0EFE21092 2012-05-11 [SC]
Key fingerprint = 8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374 2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) cdimage@ubuntu.com

shunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
gpg: can't open signed data 'SHA256SUMS'
gpg: can't hash datafile: No such file or directory

shunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS.txt
gpg: Signature made Thu Apr 23 09:46:21 2020 EDT
gpg: using RSA key D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: Good signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) cdimage@ubuntu.com" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg: There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374 2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092

shunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ sha256sum ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso
e5b72e9cfe20988991c9cd87bde43c0b691e3b67b01f76d23f8150615883ce11 ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso

shunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ sha256sum -c <(grep ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso SHA256SUMS)
grep: SHA256SUMS: No such file or directory
sha256sum: /dev/fd/63: no properly formatted SHA256 checksum lines found

shunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ sha256sum -c <(grep ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso SHA256SUMS.txt)
^[[A^[[

ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
shunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ sha256sum -c <(grep ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso SHA256SUMS.txt)
ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer, I might be confused or, you're right I am making this extra complicated, I'm just trying to err on the cautions side. I maybe was not really clear in the question and it is a lot of code. I got it verified with the RSA key and the ISO is ok against the SHA256 checksum. I just seen every example onlie shows a RSA and a DSA key. I only get an RSA key no matter what I do. I just wanna know if the RSA key is OK to check it with no DSA key. Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confused.

*RSA/DSA* have to do with [authentication](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5096/rsa-vs-dsa-for-ssh-authentication-keys) and encryption.  If you are trying to verify the **integrity** of your ISO for Ubuntu, you do that by comparing **checksums**.

Integrity/verification checks can be done with 100% accuracy by running a [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) function on a file and comparing the result to the published checksum for that file.

The following is a demonstration showing how a checksum function makes it easy to determine if a file is corrupted or has been altered.  Even the slightest error or alteration of a file will result in a radically different checksum:

[image: By Original by Helix84, adapted by Jorge Stolfi - Created by adapting Hash function.svg, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=5248938]

---

### **To verify an Ubuntu ISO:**

1. **Obtain the published checksum**.

   You can navigate to the appropriate release using: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

   Assume we are checking Ubuntu 20.04 (`ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso`).  You would click the link corresponding to "*Ubuntu*", then "*20.04*" (or "*Focal*").  Then you would open the file `SHA256SUMS` (or whichever checksum algorithm you are using),  Now you can see file names with their associated checksums.
2. **Run the checksum function on your downloaded ISO.**

   You can do this using a terminal:

   ```
   sha256sum /path/to/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso
   ```

   Wait for the checksum to be generated and you will receive a result:

   ```
   e5b72e9cfe20988991c9cd87bde43c0b691e3b67b01f76d23f8150615883ce11 ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso
   ```
3. **Compare the generated checksum to the published checksum:**

   You can copy-paste each into a notepad on separate lines.  If they are identical, then you can be sure that the file is not corrupted.

   ```
   e5b72e9cfe20988991c9cd87bde43c0b691e3b67b01f76d23f8150615883ce11
   e5b72e9cfe20988991c9cd87bde43c0b691e3b67b01f76d23f8150615883ce11
   ```

Comment: Thank You so much for the answer, yeah I think the way I said it was wrong. I was able to run the check sum and the authentication check but I only got an RSA key to authenticate when I ran the script in BASH.All the examples I saw had a DSA and an RSA key,
This is what I followed: (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#4-retrieve-the-correct-signature-key)
This is my result:
"shunix@DESKTOP-74T9H9J:/mnt/c/UBUNTU ISO CKSUM$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS.txt gpg: Signature made Thu Apr 23 09:46:21 2020 EDT gpg: using RSA key D94AA3F0EFE21092"

Comment: I installed it and it was a good copy, I'm trying to develop best practices when learning about Ubuntu and Linux in general, I really appreciate the explanation it was a great help in understanding the checksum concept and the chart was awesome too !